# Delphi DeleteFile после CopyFile

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Копирую файл из одной папки в другую, после пытаюсь удалить один из файлов в папке, в которую скопировал, но он не удаляется. В чем проблема?

Копирование файла:

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   CopyFile(PChar('Путь к копируемому файлу'), PChar('Путь к папке в которую копируем', false );

end;
```

Удаление:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DeleteFile('Путь к файлу') then
    ShowMessage('Файл удален')
  else
    ShowMessage('Не удалось удалить файл:(');
end;
```

После вызова функции CopyFile, DeleteFile не срабатывает.

Comment: Покажите Ваш код.

Comment: А как связано удаление файла и "загружается"?

Comment: ну, копируется, перепутал)

Comment: добавил код выше, внес ещё изменения

Comment: @KRasul и все же какая последовательность? CoptFile, потом DeleteFile возвращает ошибку?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Выбираю файл в диалогов окне, он копируется в папку, после чего listbox обновляется, потом выбираю другой файл в listbox и удаляю другой кнопкой, но он не удаляется. Если не использовать до удаления CopyFile то все норм.

Comment: Был бы чистый WinAPI - можно было бы GetLastError дернуть и посмотреть причину...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов он вообще не получает файл по адресу, когда пытается удалить. Даже не представляю, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: "он вообще не получает файл по адресу" - это, простите КАК?! DeleteFile получает параметром строку (!!!) с путем к удаляемому файлу. Адреса нет.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну а я о чем) Под строкой я имел в виду адрес, это же путь к удаляемому файлу.

Comment: Это называется ПУТЬ. И что значит "не получает". DeleteFile ничего не должна получать, она должна удалять. В общем, вам помочь нельзя.

Comment: @KromStern так все норм, выходит, я привел код, проблема - после использования CopyFile, DeleteFile не работает, писал уже.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну ошибся словом, чего уж тут) Понятно что он удаляет файл. Я к тому что он файл вовсе не находит.

Comment: Как вы выяснили что файл не находится?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов там есть функция listUpdate, в ней я использую функцию FindFirst, которая ищет файлы, так она совсем не срабатывает. tsr.Name также ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Специально выделил жирным - **минимальный код для её воспроизведения**, а не 3 экрана кода не относящегося к делу ;-)

Comment: Ну извините, я думал так будет понятнее что происходит)

Comment: Видимо, никто не сможет помочь. Придётся самому искать)

Comment: @KRasul Сам процесс создания минимального кода для воспроизведения ошибки наверняка поможет вам понять, что у вас не так. А если не поможет, то, запостив его сюда вы сможете быстро получить ответ на свой вопрос. P.S. Как правильно спрашивать про код: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#code

Comment: @kot-da-vinci так первый код общий просто, а, как вы говорите, минимальный, находится после слов копирование и удаление.

Comment: Продолжайте сокращать свой пример кода, убирайте все лишнее.

Comment: @KromStern сократил. Попробуйте хотя бы сделать как в моем примере) А то чувство что все озабочены только тем как я вопрос составил)

Comment: И убедитесь теперь, что "путь к файлу" у вас точно совпадает!

Comment: @KromStern так если воспользоваться функцией DeleteFile до использования CopyFile, то все норм, удаление работает. Сама функция CopyFile тоже работает нормально, т.е копирует файл.

Comment: Приведенный код сам по себе работает (только что проверил у себя на сетевой папке). И работает у 10000 других людей. Ошибка у тебя в чем-то еще. И вот подталкивая тебя сократить пример, мы учим тебя заниматься отладкой тех вещей, которые известны только тебе (пути, имена файлов, и т.п.). Может быть у тебя лишний пробел где-то в имени вклеен, имя не то, или мало ли что еще. Delete работает если ты скопировал руками или после перезапуска программы?

Comment: после перезапуска. Ладно, буду дальше разбираться. Если что напишу)

Comment: Все работает: `program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

begin
    CopyFile(PChar('1.tmp'), PChar('Test Folder\1.tmp'), False);

    if DeleteFile(PChar('1.tmp')) then
      Writeln('Файл удален')
    else
      Writeln('Не удалось удалить файл:(');
    Readln;
end.` Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Прописал пути вручную, сработало. Видимо, проблема в путях все же) Буду проверять значения всех переменных.

Comment: Блин, проблема оказалось в том, что я использовал относительные пути. Эх, извините, что потревожил вас)

Answer (score 1):

*Перенес ответ KRasul из комментариев:*

> Блин, проблема оказалось в том, что я использовал относительные пути. Эх, извините, что потревожил вас)

---

От себя: Поэтому так важно приводить минимальный воспроизводимый код. В большинстве случаев, при его составлении ошибка всплывает сама собой.

> Приведенный код сам по себе работает (только что проверил у себя на сетевой папке). И работает у 10000 других людей. Ошибка у тебя в чем-то еще. И вот подталкивая тебя сократить пример, мы учим тебя заниматься отладкой тех вещей, которые известны только тебе (пути, имена файлов, и т.п.). Может быть у тебя лишний пробел где-то в имени вклеен, имя не то, или мало ли что еще.